# ¿Puedo convertir un PDF con tablas, gráficas, datos a word? sin perder la forma del PDF original

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, spyder

He probado con el paquete pip pypdf2 pero solo convierte texto. Utilizo python 3.9

Comment: Esta pregunta (en el sitio en ingles) responde a tu duda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358281/convert-pdf-to-doc-python-bash

Comment: La respuesta corta es: no, word no va a representar el pdf exactamente igual que el original. Pero el quid de la cuestión es "exactamente". La solución que propone @DanteS. es un muy buen parche